# Python code giving error

Tags: python

My code isn't working, please help! I have a project due in programming and I just can't figure out. It's giving me the this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/breakingcodeccc.py", line 258, in <module>
    decodeorencode()
  File "C:/Python27/breakingcodeccc.py", line 14, in decodeorencode
    encode ()
  File "C:/Python27/breakingcodeccc.py", line 61, in encode
    for letters in secretmessage:
   TypeError: 'bool' is not interable
```

I've tried everything to get this to work. When I push decode it just repeats and when I encode it won't even encode. I'm a newbie by the way.

```
print "Hey there user"
global message

def decodeorencode():
    valid_answer = False
    while valid_answer == False:

        message = str(raw_input('would you like to encode or decode? '))
        if message.lower() == "encode" :
            encode()
        elif message.lower() == "decode":
            print "We will now decode your message!"
            response = str(raw_input( 'do you know the key? '))
            if response in (['yes', 'Yes', 'y', 'Y']):
                decode()
            elif response in (['no', 'No', 'n', 'N']):
                random_decode()

alphabetupper = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y','Z']   
alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
dmessage = []
emessage = []
rdmessage = []

def encode ():
    print "We will now encode your message!"
    secretmessage = str(raw_input("Please enter your message now."))
    valid_anwser = True
    keyy = int(raw_input("Please pick a key between 1 to 26"))
    secretmessage = secretmessage.isupper()
    for letters in secretmessage:
        one_letter = letters

        if one_letter.isalpha() == True:
           number = alphabetupper.index(one_letter) + keyy
           if number <= 26:
               letter = alphabetupper[number]
               emessage.append(letter)
               break
           else:
               letter = number % 26
               letter = alphabetupper[letter]
               emessage.append(letter)
               break

        elif letters.isalpha == False:
            emessage.append(letters)
            break

        return emessage

def decode():
    valid_answer = True
    secretmessage = str(raw_input("Please enter your message now."))
    keyy = int(raw_input("Please pick a key between 1 to 26"))
    keyy = - keyy
    for letters in secretmessage:

        if letters.isalpha()== True and letters.isupper() == True:
           number = alphabetupper.index(letters)+ keyy
           if number <= 26:
               letter = alphabetupper[number]
               dmessage.append(letter)
               break
           else:
               letter = number%26
               letter = alphabetupper[letter]
               dmessage.append(letter)
               break

        elif letters.isalpha() == True and letters.islower() == True:
            number = alphabet.index(letters) + keyy
            if number <= 26:
               letter = number
               letter = alphabet [letter]
               dmessage.append(letter)
               break
            else:
               letter = number % 26
               letter = alphabet[letter]
               dmessage.append(letter)
               break

        elif letters.isalpha == False:
            rdmessage.append(letter)

    return dmessage

def random_decode ():
    valid_answer = True
    secretmessage = str(raw_input("Please enter your message now."))
    valid_answer = False
    keyy = 1
    while valid_answer == False:
        keyy = - keyy
        for letters in secretmessage:

            if letters.isalpha() == True and letters.isupper() == True:
                number = alphabetupper.index(letters)+ keyy
                if number <= 26:
                    letter = number
                    rdmessage.append(letter)
                    key += 1
                    break
                else:
                    letter = number % 26
                    letter = alphabetupper[letter]
                    rdmessage.append(letter)
                    key += 1
                    break

            elif letters.isalpha() == True and letters.islower() == True:
                number = alphabet.index(letters)+ keyy
                if number <= 26:
                    letter = number
                    rdmessage.append(letter)
                    key += 1
                    break
                else:
                    letter = number % 26
                    letter = alphabet[letter]
                    rdmessage.append(letter)
                    key += 1
                    break

            elif letters.isalpha == False:
                rdmessage.append(letters)

       return rdmessage

decodeorencode()
```

Answer (score 1):

This line here

```
secretmessage = secretmessage.isupper()
```

is converting your message to a boolean (true or false), which is the return of the [`isupper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) function. You probably wanted simply [`upper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to convert it to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong; `secretmessage` is a boolean (i.e. `True` or `False`) and you can't iterate through it. The error stems from this line:

```
secretmessage = secretmessage.isupper()
```

[`str.isupper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) returns `True` or `False`. Instead of this, you should have:

```
secretmessage = secretmessage.upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

secretmessage.upper() not .isupper()  isupper() IS asking a question to which the answer is true or false.

Comment: that's `isupper()` actually, not `isUpper()`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - whoops - got caught - you are very correct. :)